# Site styling - part of image not shown until resize

Tags: html, css, image, resize

On this site http://www.vicetone.com/ , the main header picture is shown, when you resize the page by the x-axis the top of the picture is revealed showing the full size of the picture upon resizing. Could anyone enlighten me pn how this has been achieved as I'm planning to use this method in a site.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They give the image a fixed height and a width of 100%. They align the image to the bottom. When you scale the page down, the image scales down too. So when you scale down your browser it will scale down the image. The scaling down happens from the bottom of the fixed height. So your image always needs to be bigger then the fixed height. You can hide parts of the image using background-size: cover.

It will do the following:

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

This will do the trick for you:

HTML:

```
<div id="headerimage"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#headerimage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url(header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    position: relative;
}
```

You can easily change things in it. If you want to reveal parts of the image from the bottom you just change the background-position from bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

it's done using the CSS property `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by using the [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) at-rule. In this case, the image changes size via having a width of 100%, so it's always 100% of the width of the page, but the height is changed via the at-rule. On this site, this is done by adding

```
@media screen and (max-width:840px) {
    #header {
        height: 550px; 
    }
    /*other styling for screens of 840px wide and smaller*/
}
@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
    #header {
        height: 400px;
    }
    /*other styling for screens of 760px wide and smaller*/
}
/*etc*/
```

This makes the `#header` image change height depending on the screen size. You can also make the image smoothly resize its height via the screen width, by just adding `height:auto;` instead of the different heights at different screen sizes.

PS: I suggest using Google Chrome, or Firefox in combination with [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), so that you can see these things for yourself (if you've got some experience with web developing).